# Apache "Order" directive rationale

Tags: web, apache, httpd.conf

It sounds like the basic difference between "Order deny,allow" and "Order allow,deny" is that the former is permissive ("Allow" directives are prioritized, and anyone is allowed by default) and the latter is prohibitive ("Deny" directives are prioritized and no one is allowed by default).

Assuming I understand correctly, this is extremely unintuitive, and I'm wondering why the Order directive works this way. What's the underlying rationale? E.g., is this someone's idea of a good way to express access control? is it computationally advantageous to have requests processed in different orders? is this more for the sake of extensibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing non-trivial access control, there will be times when two rules match the same request.  When they conflict (ie: one says "deny" and the other says "allow"), you need some way of deciding which one takes precedence.   Or, there will be cases where no rule matches, and you need a default policy to cover those cases.

In Apache it's called `Order`, and works like it does, mostly because of how Apache decided to handle access control.  The way it handles them, rules are broken up into "allow" rules and "deny" rules. When a request comes in, processing conceptually happens like this:

1. Apache runs the Deny rules first if the order is `deny,allow`, or the Allow rules first if the order is `allow,deny`.
2. Apache runs the other rules.
3. The last match wins.  If there are no matches, the last action in the `Order` is the policy.

(There are apparently some optimizations to this process.  Supposedly in `allow,deny`, if an Allow rule isn't matched, Apache doesn't even bother with Deny rules, cause it'd already deny the request anyway.  Likewise, if no Deny rule is matched in `deny,allow`, the request is allowed (because there's nothing left to stop it).  But conceptually, you can consider both sets of rules to run.)

I suppose it'd be possible to give each rule a priority param or something, and have the admin decide what priorities to give everything.  Frankly, though, it's not worth all that trouble when all you want to do is know whether to allow or deny something.  Since that's accomplished easily enough by either giving either the "allow" or "deny" rules a chance to override the other based on processing order, that's what they did.  But different sites may well require that the other set of rules take priority, so they made it configurable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it helps to shed some light on intended use. I can see how this *might* be useful in some situations, but I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around a use-case where toggling the "Order" directive trumps simply giving precedence to the first "Allow" or "Deny" directive encountered for a scope. The latter approach seems more flexible and more intuitive.

Comment: Question is, though...what happens when you have rules from different scopes?  The intuitiveness breaks down considerably if you have... say... global default policies, site-specific overrides, location-specific rules, directory-specific rules, *sub*-directory rules, stuff in .htaccess files, etc etc etc.  Any way you handle it, you're gonna break someone's use case.  Unless you give them a way specify the order in which those rules are applied for a given site...oh, wait...  :)  Turns out, `Order` is one of those simple things that work.  Anything more would have to justify its complexity.

Comment: I'm still skeptical, but I'm marking this as the right answer. Thanks.